# JOLT transformation filter a list about the first string element

Tags: json, list, jolt

I would like to search a list for the first real string element (which could be not a number) and output this.

*Input* :

```json
{
  "firstString": [
    "0.20",
    "test",
    "0.30"
  ]
}
```

or

```json
{
  "firstString": [
    "0.20",
    "0,30",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

*Expected Output* :

```json
{
  "readingS": "test"
}
```

The order of the element can change, either it comes to 2nd or 3rd placeholder. The list is maximum 3 elements long.
My thought was to go over either the last or middle element, however this does not work. The list is generated just before with the modify-overwrite-beta.

Comment: Probably it's worth sharing the original input json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation along with **toInteger** conversion such as

```json
[
  //Determine the elements whether toInteger conversion is applicable for them
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "arr": "=(@(1,firstString))",
      "0": "=toInteger(@(1,arr[0]))",
      "1": "=toInteger(@(1,arr[1]))",
      "2": "=toInteger(@(1,arr[2]))"
    }
  },
  //The arrays are generated from the elements which are eligible to
  //conversion, while not for the others
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "arr": { "*": "&" }
    }
  },
  //The arrays are removed, so all numeric ones by reversing
  //key-value pairs
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  //Reverse back the pairs
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "readingS[#2]"
      }
    }
  },
  //and pick the leftmost element
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have some values that ended with numbers. So we can match all values that ended with the number, and we have a real string in the last.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "firstString": {
        "*": {
          "*0": "",
          "*1": "",
          "*2": "",
          "*3": "",
          "*4": "",
          "*5": "",
          "*6": "",
          "*7": "",
          "*8": "",
          "*9": "",
          "*": {
            "$": "readingS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it would fail for the string values ending with integers such as `test1`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan True, But I thought the strings that could exist are similar to the question, So my answer not working for string ended with a number.